# C# Stitching small pictures into one large one

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have an objective: I need to join, for example 2 pictures like https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQQC5.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDDMZ.jpg. In the result there has to be and image like https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xivu.jpg not https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrTnS.jpg.

I'll explain in words: I have some images with the same areas and I need to find the area, crop it in one image and after this join them.

Comment: You might want to start with images using lossless compression.  That way you wouldn't have to consider compression artifacts in the images as you process them.

Comment: This is commonly called *image stitching*.  I suggest that you change the title of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/automatic_panoramas.aspx), it's explains a possible solutions using the C# [Aforge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/) image processing library

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is read the pixel values into arrays,
then find overlapping area using an algorithm like correlation
or min cut.

After finding coordinates of overlap, write out both images into
new array, use coordinates relative to large image minus
position of overlap in that source image plus position in destination image.

C# is not a factor in solving this, unless you meant
to ask about existing .NET frameworks that can help.

Answer (score -1):

I am developing .NET library called [SharpStitch](http://www.imagingshop.com/sharpstitch) (commercial) which can do the job.

It uses feature-based image alignment for general purpose image stitching.